# NHibernate session and transaction implementation

Tags: c#, database, http, session, hibernate

In order to create loose coupling architecture on my web applications, I have created my own implementation for ORM, in this case, NHibernate.

I want you please to review the code and tell me if you think it can work in a real world on high traffic app.

I have divided the API to transaction and session.  There are some cases where I want to use session with out transaction, and there are times when I need multiple transaction in a single HTTP request.

This is the session API:

```
public interface IDalSession : IDisposable 
{
    IDalSession Start();
    IDalTransaction StartWithTransaction();
    bool IsActive();

    T Save<T>(T entity);
    IQueryOver<T> QueryOver<T>() where T : class;
    IQueryable<T> Query<T>() where T : class;
    T CreateQuery<T>(string query) where T : class;
    void ExecuteUpdate(string sqlQuery);
}
```

This is the transaction API:

```
public interface IDalTransaction : IDisposable
    {
        bool IsActive { get; }
        void MarkForRollBack();
        void Commit();

        T Save<T>(T entity);
        IQueryOver<T> QueryOver<T>() where T : class;
        IQueryable<T> Query<T>() where T : class;
        T CreateQuery<T>(string query) where T : class;
        void ExecuteUpdate(string sqlQuery);
    }
```

This is the session factory (the session suppose to exist per HTTP request):
**I am aware that I am coupled with the MySQL call below; it will be removed.**

```
public class NHibernateSessionFactory
    {
        public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory;

        public static void Configure(DatabaseConnectionProperties database)
        {
            if (SessionFactory == null)
            {
                FluentConfiguration configuration;
                configuration = Fluently.Configure().Database(
                    MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(
                        mysql =>
                        mysql.Database(database.DatabaseName).Username(database.UserName).Password(database.Password).
                            Server(database.Host)
                        ));

                foreach (Type entity in database.Entities)
                {
                    configuration.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(entity.Assembly)
                                                    .Conventions.Add(new LowerCaseWithUnderConvention())

                        );
                }
                if (database.GenerateTables)
                {
                    configuration.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true));
                }
                else
                {
                    configuration.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg));
                }
                configuration.ExposeConfiguration(
                    c => c.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "web"));

                SessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
            }
        }

        public static ISession GetCurrentSession()
        {
            if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(SessionFactory))
            {
                CurrentSessionContext.Bind(SessionFactory.OpenSession());
            }
            return SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        }

        public static IDalSession OpenSession()
        {
            return new DalSession(SessionFactory);
        }

        public static void CloseSession()
        {
            SessionFactory.Close();
        }
    }
```

This is how I inject the session per request:

```
   kernel.Bind<IDalSession>()
            .ToProvider<HttpDalSessionProvider>()
            .InRequestScope();
```

This is how I provide it to Ninject:

```
public class HttpDalSessionProvider : Provider<IDalSession>
    {
        private static DatabaseConnectionProperties GetDatabaseConnectionProperties()
        {
            List<Type> entities = new List<Type> {typeof (BillingInfo)};
            return new DatabaseConnectionProperties(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbHost"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbName"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbUser"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbPassword"],
                entities,true
                );
        }
        protected override IDalSession CreateInstance(IContext context)
        {
            NHibernateSessionFactory.Configure(GetDatabaseConnectionProperties());
            return NHibernateSessionFactory.OpenSession().Start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I've seen many attempts to abstract particular ORM from application, and all of them at a certain stage of maturity had to break this abstraction. One of the reasons for that is when you need to optimize certain use cases (like eager-loading related entities, or combining several round trips to server into one) you'll need to use ORM specifics that you're abstracting from.

And another (more obvious) reason why I vote against abstracting ORMs from the code is that ORM is already an abstraction, so what you do is an abstraction on top of another abstraction that brings little benefits.

There is a very good series of articles that describes best practices for managing NHibernate in ASP.NET:

- [Refactoring toward frictionless & odorless code: The baseline](http://ayende.com/blog/4803/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-the-baseline)
- [Refactoring toward frictionless & odorless code: Hiding global state](http://ayende.com/blog/4804/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-hiding-global-state)
- [Refactoring toward frictionless & odorless code: Limiting session scope](http://ayende.com/blog/4805/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-limiting-session-scope)
- [Refactoring toward frictionless & odorless code: A broken home (controller)](http://ayende.com/blog/4806/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-a-broken-home-controller)
- [Refactoring toward frictionless & odorless code: The case for the view model](http://ayende.com/blog/4807/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-the-case-for-the-view-model)
- [Refactoring toward frictionless & odorless code: Getting rid of globals](http://ayende.com/blog/4808/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-getting-rid-of-globals)
- [Refactoring toward frictionless & odorless code: What about transactions?](http://ayende.com/blog/4809/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-what-about-transactions)

Comment: Thank you, please note that this is not an abstract implementation, this is a wrapper. I just want to avoid  external dependencies across my systems.

Comment: I meant exactly that: you are trying to *abstract* your system from NHibernate